# No flames when rendering

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, 3d-view, smoke-simulation

I am creating a simple animation with fire in Blender Render. A followed a tutorial to make an animation with flames. The flames in the viewport but when I try to render my animation/image the flames don't show up. Where is my problem?

[.blend file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8t8Tx32g5JeWktsX2EzOU01VlU)

Comment: Not using Cycles and GPU are you?

Comment: Your .blend link is locked, try uploading it to [BlendExchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) instead.

Comment: Please edit your question and add images that show how the materials are setup in your scene

Comment: Make it easier for others to help you. Having to get permission to download your file only makes it harder for you to get an answer...