# No flame in Blender Render

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, smoke-simulation

I am creating a simple animation with flame. I followed a tutorial and flame appears in viewport but is not present when creating an animation or image. I am using Blender Render (not Cycles and GPU which seems to be a common problem). What seems to be my issue?

[image]

Comment: please delete your old duplicate question: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45979/no-flames-when-rendering and keep this one, it's better.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot delete it, I posted it as guest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with mapping the domain materials textures, this is how it should be:

[image]

Set both your *Smoke* and *Fire* textures like this. The domain object is *Cube.003* and not *Icosphere* and the mapping is *Generated*.

Comment: Thank you, it works now. I thought you had to set the material to the iconsphere as the fire should be coming out of it. It works now that I set it to the domain.